# How to display the content of Java ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

This is my `Data` class:

```
public class Data {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    Data(String n,int a){
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return(name);
    }

    public void setName(String n){
        name = n;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return(age);
    }

    public void setAge(int a){
        age = a;
    }

    public void Print(){
        System.out.print(("("+GetName()));
        System.out.print(",");
        System.out.print(GetAge());
        System.out.print(") ");
    }
}
```

This is my `CS1702_Lab5` class that uses `ArrayList` and that is supposed to print the content of `ArrayList`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CS1702_Lab5 {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();
        data.add(new Data("Fred", 21));
    }

    private static void PrintDataArray(ArrayList<Data> data) {
        for(int i=0;i<data.size();++i){
            data.get(i).Print();
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to add new Data which is a StringName and IntAge and then display it but it doesn't seem to work. The console is empty nothing is printed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please read the naming conventions and apply them

Comment: If you want to call the print method, you have to add it to your main, it won't automagically know what you meant it to do. Computers are extremely pedantic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `PrintDataArray()` method from `main()`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CS1702_Lab5 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();
        data.add(new Data("Fred", 21));
        PrintDataArray(data);  // YOU NEED TO ADD THIS LINE.
    }

    private static void PrintDataArray(ArrayList<Data> data) {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i) {
            data.get(i).Print();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

You never called your print method from `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ArrayList<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();
    data.add(new Data("Fred", 21));
    PrintDataArray(data);
}
```

you never called `PrintDataArray`

Answer (score 0):

Call the Print `PrintDataArray` method in the main method

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
{
ArrayList<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();
data.add(new Data("Fred", 21));
here>PrintDataArray(data);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't call the method `PrintDataArray(data)` in your main method...

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ArrayList<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();
    data.add(new Data("Fred", 21));
    CS1702_Lab5.PrintDataArray(data);
}
```

> Note: please read naming conventions in Java and try to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Add PrintDataArray() inside your main method

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    {
    ArrayList<Data> data = new ArrayList<Data>();
    data.add(new Data("Fred", 21));
    PrintDataArray(data);
    }
    }

    private static void PrintDataArray(ArrayList<Data> data) 
    {
        for(int i=0;i<data.size();++i)

        {
            data.get(i).Print();
        }
    }
}
```